# Finding volume and lowest point in subbasins using GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I have created 156 subbasins from initial raster. 
Now for **any** subbasins I need to have the volume of raster and the lowest point and insert in second moment in a table. I use Grass Gis software.

What is the better way for it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `r.univar` with the `zones` option. The basins raster will be the zones, and the original dem will be the input map. The results will be put into a file you specify.

If the basins are already polygons, the `v.rast.stats` will also work. The results appear as additional attributes in the polygon vector's attribute table.

Comment: Ok thank you Micha, but I want use the originale DEM without subdivide in 156 small raster. Can use the shapefile of subbasins to calculate the stats of DEM? Best Regards

Comment: Ok I try, but dont look the volume of single subbasins. It's necessary calculate before the r.clump of DEM?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. If you have a vector of polygons, individual basins in this case, then v.rast.stats will collect statistics from the DEM for each individual basin: area, average height, max and min heights, etc.

Comment: Ok for stats, but for of single subbabasins? I think to use the raster of subbabsins to use with r.clump and calculate the volume? It's correct? Best Regards

Comment: Again, if you have a vector of subbasins, then run `v.rast.stats` with the dem as the raster parameter, and you will get additional columns in the vector attribute table with values for MIN, MAX, SUM, MEAN and other stats from the raster **for each subbasin** . Hope that's clear.